# Avro Schema: multiple records reference same data type issue: Unknown union branch

Tags: schema, avro, avro-tools

I have Avro Schema: customer record import the CustomerAddress subset.

```
[
  {
      "type": "record",
      "namespace": "com.example",
      "name": "CustomerAddress",
      "fields": [
        { "name": "address", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "city", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "postcode", "type": ["string", "int"] },
        { "name": "type","type": {"type": "enum","name": "type","symbols": ["POBOX","RESIDENTIAL","ENTERPRISE"]}}
      ]
  },
  {
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.example",
     "name": "Customer",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first_name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "middle_name", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null },       
       { "name": "last_name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "age", "type": "int" },
       { "name": "height", "type": "float" },
       { "name": "weight", "type": "float" },
       { "name": "automated_email", "type": "boolean", "default": true },
       { "name": "customer_emails", "type": {"type": "array","items": "string"},"default": []},
       { "name": "customer_address", "type": "com.example.CustomerAddress" }
     ]
  }
]
```

i have JSON payload:

```
{
    "Customer" : {
         "first_name": "John",
         "middle_name": null,
         "last_name": "Smith",
         "age": 25,
         "height": 177.6,
         "weight": 120.6,
         "automated_email": true,
         "customer_emails": ["ning.chang@td.com", "test@td.com"],
         "customer_address":
         {
             "address": "21 2nd Street",
             "city": "New York",
             "postcode": "10021",
             "type": "RESIDENTIAL"
         }
    }
}
```

when i runt the command: `java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar fromjson --schema-file customer.avsc customer.json`

got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch Customer
```

Comment: This isn't how you cross-reference Avro schemas using `avro-tools`. They need to be fully-embedded. Besides, I suggest you try using IDL instead  https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you have simple example i can follow?

Comment: `{record ... fields: [..., { "name": "customer_address", "type":  {"type" : "record",... namespace, name, fields...}}]} ` or, like I said, use IDL where you define schemas much like Java classes (see the documentation), then use `idl2schemeta` command from the jar to get your AVSC (assuming you need it)

Comment: Also note that the top level `"Customer"` key is an Object value itself, so you actually have 3 Avro "records" needed for that JSON

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON data you use the key `Customer` but you have to use the fully qualified name. So it should be `com.example.Customer`.